# Linear combination of discrete variables $T_i$ with $P(T_i=1)=P(T_i=-1)=1/2$

Tags: probability, random-variable, bernoulli-distribution

Let $T_1,...,T_n$ be iid with a Rademacher distribution; *i.e.*, $P(T_i=1)=P(T_i=-1)=1/2$; and let $w = (w_1,...,w_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ without further constraints on $w$.

Is there a way to compute $P(T_1\sum_{i=1}^n T_i w_i \geq 0)$ without stepping through all $2^n$ possible outcomes for the $T$'s?

Comment: Are some additional conditions assumed, such as $w_i \ge 0$ $\forall i$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n=1$? What about the dependence among the $T_i$ -- are they assumed to be iid?

Comment: No further conditions. Yes, iid.

Comment: I don't think this problem has an interesting solution if one doesn't place at least some conditions on the possible values of the terms $w_i$, $i=1,\ldots,n$. Put $Y=T_1(\sum_{i=1}^n w_iT_i)= w_1+T_1(\sum_{i=2}^n w_i T_i)$ (since $T_1^2\equiv1$). If $w_1$ is (say) a large positive number s.t. $w_1>\sum_{i=2}^n|w_i|$, then $P(Y\ge0)=1$. For a non-trivial result, I think one needs, at the very least, some kind of bound on $\max_i w_i/(\sum |w_i|)$.

Comment: @Mico Your analysis reduces the question to a slight generalization: compute $\Pr(\sum_{i=2}^n T_iw_i\ge-w_1)$. No bounds are needed on the $w_i$ in order to analyze that problem. Of greater relevance would be information about the relative sizes of the $w_i^2$ and the size of $n$, because that would permit good approximate solutions.

Comment: @whuber - Real quick: shouldn't there be a factor $T_1$ multiplying $\sum_{i=2}^n w_i T_i$? To exclude trivial solutions (i.e., those with probability $0$ and $1$), one does need *some* restrictions on $w_i$, possibly with some linkage to $n$, right?

Comment: @Mico Technically, yes, but a little reflection will suggest how to get rid of it: upon multiplying everything by $T_1$, that factor disappears from the sum and reappears multiplied by $w_1$. You can therefore split the problem into two cases: one where $T_1=1$ and the other where $T_1=-1$ (and $-w_1$ is replaced by $w_1$ and the $\ge$ is replaced by $\le$). So you can solve those two (essentially identical) problems and combine the solutions. No constraints are needed on any of the $w_i$ to develop a general solution--but it's going to be messy.

Comment: I guess one could "step through" all possible combinations of the $T_2,...,T_n$'s outcomes. That should be easy to do using some loop but computationally inefficient. Unluckily there are no restrictions on the $w_i$.

Comment: Are you looking for a numerical computation given a set of $w_i$ or some kind of algebraic approximation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes.**

**Let's begin by simplifying the question.**  The event

$$T_1\sum_{i=1}^n T_i w_i \geq 0$$

is the union of the disjoint events (determined by $T_1=\pm 1$)

$$w_1 + \sum_{i=2}^n T_i w_i \geq 0,\ -w_1 + \sum_{i=2}^n T_i w_i \geq 0.$$

After simple algebraic manipulation, and using the fact that each $T_i$ has the same distribution as $-T_i$ (it is "symmetric"), these events are both equivalent to those of the form

$$\sum_{i=2}^n T_i w_i \leq w$$

for $w=\pm w_1$.  Again exploiting the symmetries of the $T_i$ (to make all the $w_i$ non-negative) and re-ordering them, this can be written

$$\sum_{i=2}^n T_i |w_i| \leq w$$

where $|w_2| \ge |w_3| \ge \cdots \ge |w_n|$.

We need to compute the chances of two such events and wish to do so efficiently.  I will assume that the chance needs to be computed to high accuracy, so that approximations would be unacceptable.  (For many configurations of the $|w_i|$, Normal approximations to the distributions might otherwise work well.  Deeper analysis can be carried out using the characteristic function $\phi$ of $\sum_{i=2}^n T_i |w_i|$, which by definition is $$\phi(t) = \prod_{i=2}^n\left(\frac{\exp(-j |w_i|t)}{2} + \frac{\exp(j |w_i|t)}{2}\right)=\prod_{i=2}^n\cos(w_it);$$ $j = \sqrt{-1}$.)

---

From now on, reduce $n$ by $1$, start the indexing with $i=1$, and assume all the $w_i$ are positive.  (Obviously, any zero values can be ignored.)  Let $1 \le k \lt n$.  Consider the distribution of $X = \sum_{i=1}^n T_i w_i$ conditional on the first $k$ values of $T_i$:

$$\Pr(X \le w\,|\, T_1, \ldots, T_k) = {\Pr}_{(T_{k+1},\ldots,T_n)}\left(\sum_{i=k+1}^n T_i w_i \le w - \sum_{i=1}^k T_i w_i = w_0\right).$$

Since $|T_i| \le 1$, the left hand sum is bounded:

$$-u_{k+1} = -(w_{k+1} + \cdots + w_n) \le \sum_{i=k+1}^n T_i w_i \le w_{k+1} + \cdots + w_n = u_{k+1}.$$

Let $u_{k+1}$ be the right hand side: it is a cumulative sum of the $w_i$, accumulated from the rightmost (lowest) values.  Obviously now if $u_{k+1} \le w_0$ then $X \le w$ is certain; and if  $-u_{k+1} \gt w_0$, then $X \le w$ has zero probability.  **This leads to a simple *branch and bound* algorithm,** because we needn't search any further to assess the distribution.  Whereas exhaustive enumeration would have had to examine $2^{n-k}$ possible cases, we have made a determination of their contribution to the distribution in $O(1)$ time.

There is not much hope that this improvement will lead to a *worst-case* algorithm that is better than $O(2^n)$ in performance (although I think it can be reduced to $O(2^{n/2})$ which--although much better--is still non-polynomial).  However, the improvement is good enough to be worth considering, especially for moderate values of $n$ where exhaustive enumeration starts becoming impracticable (somewhere above $20$ and certainly above $40$).  Let us therefore turn to benchmarking the algorithm.  How efficient is it?

The worst case is when most of the $w_i$ have comparable sizes, for then the branch-and-bound heuristic rarely accomplishes anything.  Fortunately, this is exactly the situation where the Central Limit Theorem can supply excellent approximations!  It will therefore be perhaps even more interesting to explore situations where the sizes of the $w_i$ are highly spread out.

To this end, I created four datasets with $n=15$ from four distributions with radically different shapes: Beta$(1/5,1/5)$ (sharply bimodal), Exponential (high mode near zero), Uniform, and Gamma$(20)$ (nearly Normal, with values closely arranged near $20$).  Each dataset was normalized to a maximum of $1$.  Using the branch-and-bound method, $\Pr(X \le w)$ was computed for $19$ values of $w$ ranging from $0$ up to $2\sqrt{n}$.  (Negative values of $w$ need not be shown because the distributions of $X$ are nearly symmetric.)  The figure displays the results, graphing the probabilities (the empirical cumulative distribution function of $X$) in the top row and the *efficiencies* (on log-linear scales) in the bottom row.  The "efficiency" is the ratio of the number of configurations needed for exhaustive enumeration ($2^n$) to the number of configurations considered by the branch-and-bound algorithm.

[image: Figure]

For the Beta distribution, whose strong bimodality essentially limits the calculations to the higher half of the data, efficiencies are greatest.  As expected, they are least for the Gamma distribution, whose values are all comparable.  Nevertheless, even in this difficult case, the efficiencies all exceed $3$.

The smallest efficiencies are usually for $w=0$.  Eventually efficiency will increase as $|w|$ increases.  Collectively these results are strong evidence that the approach described here not only is computationally more efficient than exhaustive enumeration, it tends to be *much* more efficient.

---

**The implementation of the algorithm is straightforward and simple.**  `R` code follows.  It includes a section that tests the algorithm (by comparing its output to an exhaustive enumeration) and another section to reproduce the figure.

```R
#
# The algorithm.
#
f <- function(w0, w) {
  w <- sort(abs(w), decreasing=TRUE)
  w.sum <- c(rev(cumsum(rev(w)))[-1], 0)
  count <- 0                              # Counts calls to f()
  f <- function(u, u.sum, w0) {
    count <<- count + 1
    y <- sapply(w0 + c(-1,1)*u[1], function(w1) {
      if (w1 < -u.sum[1]) return(0)
      if (w1 >= u.sum[1]) return(1)
      return(f(u[-1], u.sum[-1], w1))
    })
    return(mean(y)) # (This could easily be changed to accommodate 
                    # other probabilities for the T[i].)
  }
  list(Value=f(w, w.sum, w0), Count=count)
}
#
# Test with complete enumeration.  The plot pairs should exactly coincide.
#
binary <- function(a, b, zero=-1, one=1) rep(c(rep(zero, 2^a), rep(one, 2^a)), 2^b)
n <- 9
b <- sapply(1:n, function(a) binary(n-a, a-1))
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
set.seed(17)
for (i in 1:4) {
  w <- rexp(n)
  x <- b %*% w
  y <- sapply(x, function(w0) f(w0, w)$Value) #$
  plot(ecdf(x))
  points(x, y, pch=16, cex=1/2, col="Red")
}
#
# Explore the efficiencies actually achieved.
#
n <- 15
qb <- function(q) qbeta(q, 1/5, 1/5); sigma <- sqrt(1/(1+2*1/5))/2
qg <- function(q) qgamma(q, 20)
dist <- list(Gamma=qg, Normal=qnorm, Uniform=qunif, Exponential=qexp, Beta=qb)
par(mfcol=c(2,4))
for (s in c("Beta", "Exponential", "Uniform", "Gamma")) {
  d <- dist[[s]]
  w <- d(((1:n)-1/2)/n)
  w <- w / max(abs(w))
  print(c(system.time({
    y <- sapply(x <- seq(0, 2*sqrt(n), length.out=19), 
                function(w0) {x <- f(w0, w); c(x$Value, x$Count)})
  })["elapsed"], count=sum(y[2, ])))

  plot(x, y[1, ], ylim=c(1/2, 1), type="b", ylab="Probability", main=s)
  plot(x, 2^n/y[2, ], ylim=c(1, 2^n), type="b", log="y", ylab="Efficiency")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

$$T_1\sum_{i=1}^n T_i w_i = w_1 + T_1\sum_{i=2}^n T_i w_i$$

since $T_1^2 = 1$.

Write the sum as $S_{2w}$. So we are looking at the probability

$$P\left(T_1S_{2w} \geq -w_1\right) = \\P\left(T_1S_{2w} \geq -w_1 \mid T_1 =1\right)\cdot P(T_1 =1) + P\left(T_1S_{2w} \geq -w_1 \mid T_1 =-1\right)\cdot P(T_1 =-1)$$

$$\Rightarrow P\left(T_1S_{2w} \geq -w_1\right)=\frac 12 P\left(S_{2w} \geq -w_1 \right)+ \frac 12P\left(-S_{2w} \geq -w_1 \right)$$

$$=\frac 12 \Big[1-P\left(S_{2w} \leq -w_1 \right)+P\left(S_{2w} \leq w_1 \right)\Big] \tag{1}$$

Now define $Z_i \equiv  (T_i + 1)/2$. Then the $Z_i$'s are Bernoulli $(1/2)$ random variables.

So

$$S_{2w}=\sum_{i=2}^n (2Z_i-1) w_i = 2\sum_{i=2}^n Z_iw_i - \sum_{i=2}^n w_i \tag{2}$$

Inserting into $(1)$ and rearranging we obtain

$$P\left(T_1S_{2w} \geq -w_1\right) = \frac 12 \left[1-P\left(\sum_{i=2}^n Z_iw_i \leq (1/2)\sum_{i=2}^n w_i-(w_1/2) \right)+P\left(\sum_{i=2}^n Z_iw_i \leq (1/2)\sum_{i=2}^n w_i+(w_1/2) \right)\right]$$

So we need probabilities related to $S_{Zw}\equiv \sum_{i=2}^n Z_iw_i$. The [Probability Generating Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability-generating_function) , **PGF**, of a Bernoulli $(1/2)$ is

$$G_Z(z) = \frac 12(1+z)$$

and of the linear combination of independent Bernoullis

$$G_{S_{Zw}}(z) = \prod_{i=2}^{n}\left(\frac 12(1+z^{w_i})\right) = \frac 1{2^{n-1}}\prod_{i=2}^{n}(1+z^{w_i})$$

From the **PGF** we can recover the probabilities of the probability mass function and so of the cumulative distribution function that is our goal.

**AN EXAMPLE**

For exposition purposes, assume that $n=3$ and $(w_1 =2, w_2 =2, w_3 = 4)$.

Then 
$$(1/2)\sum_{i=2}^n w_i-(w_1/2) = 2, \;\;\;  (1/2)\sum_{i=2}^n w_i+(w_1/2) = 4$$

So we want to evaluate

$$P\left(T_1S_{2w} \geq -1\right) = \frac 12 \left[1-P\left(S_{Zw} \leq 2 \right)+P\left(S_{Zw} \leq 4 \right)\right]$$

$$=\frac 12 \left[1+P\left(S_{Zw} =3 \right)+P\left(S_{Zw} = 4 \right)\right]$$

In such a very simple example, we don't really need the **PGF**: given the assumed values of the weights on the Bernoullis, it is easy to see that $P\left(S_{Zw} =3 \right) = 0$ and that $P\left(S_{Zw} = 4\right) = 1/4$. So we obtain the answer, for the specific example

$$P\left(T_1S_{2w} \geq -1\right) = 5/8$$

**Verification through the PGF**
For the specific numerical example

$$G_{S_{Zw}}(z) = \frac 1{2^{n-1}}\prod_{i=2}^{n}(1+z^{w_i}) = \frac 1{4}(1+z^2)(1+z^4) = \frac 1{4}(1+z^2+z^4+z^6)$$

The relation linking the **PGF** with probabilities is ($(k)$ denoting the order of the derivative taken

$$P(S_{Zw} = k) =\frac{ G_{S_{Zw}}^{(k)}(0)}{k!}$$

We have

$$G_{S_{Zw}}^{(1)}(z) = \frac 1{4}(2z+4z^3+6z^5)$$
$$G_{S_{Zw}}^{(2)}(z) = \frac 1{4}(2+12z^2+30z^4)$$
$$G_{S_{Zw}}^{(3)}(z) = \frac 1{4}(24z+120z^3)$$
$$G_{S_{Zw}}^{(4)}(z) = \frac 1{4}(24+360z^2)$$

So

$$P\left(S_{Zw} =3 \right) = \frac{ G_{S_{Zw}}^{(3)}(0)}{3!} = 0$$
$$P\left(S_{Zw} =4 \right) = \frac{ G_{S_{Zw}}^{(4)}(0)}{4!} = \frac 1{4}$$

Therefore

$$P\left(T_1S_{2w} \geq -1\right) = \frac 12 \left[1+0+\frac 14 \right] = 5/8$$

Now imagine what would it take if the example was not so simple.

Comment: Cool answer, but $Z_i = T_i + 1/2$ is not a Bernoulli(1/2) random variable. You need $Z_i = (T_i + 1) / 2$ for that. Though your approach should still work. Just changes the algebra at the end.

Comment: @goodepic Ah, right, I confused the probabilities with the support, and I mistakenly kept in mind $T_i \in \{-1/2,1/2\}$. Thanks for spotting this, I will check whether the approach survives nevertheless.

Comment: @goodepic I think it is ok now.

Comment: Computing this PGF directly takes $2^n$ calculations: it does not seem to represent any simplification at all.

Comment: @whuber The OP presented a probability related to a random variable which was a linear combination of dependent random variables and which moreover had no nice CDF nor an easy-going PGF, if memory serves. My answer transformed "dependent" into "independent" and also provided a compact theoretic solution. These I consider improvements and value-added, which make the answer worth something. I leave the pure computational aspect to people more experienced than me.

Comment: Isn't the question purely about computation?  "Is there a way to compute ...?" BTW, I rolled back your edited title because the question explicitly states the variables $T_i$ are iid: they are not "dependent"!

Comment: @whuber I have seen many answers here -really good ones- deviating from what the OP asks, because they had something else to offer but related to the issue - and this is what I did. The linear combination is formed by $T_1T_2, T_1T_3$, and these are dependent random variables, this is why I included it in the title, although this is not the important change. You should at least have kept the "Rademacher" name -makes the thread much more search-friendly, than what it is now.

Comment: (1) "Rademacher" is in the text. (2) Since your conclusion is "imagine what would it take if the example was not so simple," your answer appears to be very much in the nature of a comment and perhaps should be posted as one. When you deviate from what is asked, and your work is more extensive than a comment, then at least explain what you are doing, please, so that people understand at the outset that you are not answering the question.

Comment: @whuber 1) Titles attract more the attention of those who read the results of the search engine. 2) So a formal theoretical treatment is a "comment" in nature - I have no comment to that. 3) I _did not_ "deviate" from what was asked. I decided to provide a theoretical solution which led to a function that being _standard_ (a PGF of a Bernoulli) provided the opportunity to simplify the subsequent computation work, since it could be already implemented in the various software available, and so the OP would not have to do the programming himself.

Comment: It would be interesting to know exactly how you think the computation has been simplified, especially in light of the last statement in your answer, which seems to suggest that the situation is just too complicated to handle. Perhaps you could provide a worked example or some code to illustrate? That would certainly help me (and maybe many others) appreciate what you have accomplished. And yes, any "formal theoretical treatment," however elegant or beautiful, that does not answer the question or appear to provide significant progress toward an answer, sounds like a comment to me.

Comment: @whuber I have to repeat what I wrote in my previous comment: I provided a solution in terms of a standard function that could already be implemented in software. So while the computation complexity may be the same, the machinery to do it would be in place so _for the user_ the whole procedure is greatly simplified. It is like the difference between writing code from scratch to evaluate, say, a bivariate normal integral, and have a software having the function CDF(B,x,y,ρ).

Comment: I can appreciate that it may be simplified for a naive user (who does not care about performance). But have you actually *tried* your solution? I have--and I simply cannot make it work for more than tiny $n$ when the $w_i$ are otherwise arbitrary real numbers. The machinery falls apart because internally it literally is having to perform an exhaustive enumeration of all cases. That's what the O.P. is explicitly asking to avoid. Maybe I am missing something? Your guidance, in the form of pseudocode or code, could help me see where I misunderstand.

Comment: @whuber In my first comment response to this exchange I said that computation is not an area of expertise for me, so obviously I have no code or guidance to offer. But nevertheless let's turn this into possibly an opportunity for me to learn something new by offering the naive thoughts: either the Probability Generating Function is already implemented as a "special function" in some software. Or then, since what I ended up with was derivatives of a function, the software must perform symbolic differentiation. Certainly, for arbitrary (large) $n$ and $\mathbf w$, anything becomes impossible.

Comment: The problem is that your function $G$ is a pgf only in a general sense: it is a [Dirichlet series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_series), not a power series. Except when the $w_i$ are all small integers (compared to their GCD), its computation is tantamount to enumerating all the possibilities. Unlike with most power-series pgfs (or cfs or cgfs), there is no gain from algebraic or analytical manipulation (if exact probabilities are needed). What it *is* good for would be developing approximate formulas for probabilities; for that it is a powerful tool.